# IBOutlet of AnimationView in lottie is not showing the animation

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I've created an `@IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!` Then on ViewController I added a `UIView` changed its class from `UIView` to `AnimationView`. The after connecting the outlet I'm adding this code in `viewDidLoad()` of my class:

```swift
let animation = Animation.named("sticky", subdirectory: "Lottie-files")
animationView.animation = animation
animationView.loopMode = .loop
animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Then in `viewDidAppear()` I've added:

```
animationView.play()
```

But when I run it nothing shows up. I also see this in the terminal:

> [Storyboard] Unknown class AnimationView in Interface Builder file.

This warning is solved by doing
[image]

But still the animation is not appearing. No warning, no error it just not displaying.

Comment: Add module `Lottie` in storyboard where you added `AnimationView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should start animation in `viewDidAppear` or something called **after** `viewDidLoad`, for example: `viewWillAppear`

   ```swift
   public override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       addAnimation(to: animationView, name: "sticky")
   }

   public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       animationView.play()
   }

   private func addAnimation(to view: AnimationView, name: String) {
       let animation = Animation.named(name, subdirectory: "Lottie-files")
       view.animation = animation
       view.loopMode = .loop
       view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
   }
   ```

   **BONUS**

   [Ekramul Hoque's Article about View Controller's Lifecycle](https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5)

---

2. **Make sure these**

   You should write `Lottie` to your view's `Identity Inspector` section in `Interface Builder`'s right bar.

   [image: Interface Builder]

---

3. Check for subdirectory path. It can be because Xcode is unable to locate file in Lottie-files subdirectory. Try moving it in the main directory and try.

Comment: It's still now showing but now I see there is a warning `Unknown class AnimationView in Interface Builder file.`

Comment: You should write `Lottie` to `Module` section in `Interface Builder` when you select your view and open `Identity Inspector`. Please check my edited answer @ChaudhryTalha

Comment: did that but still the animation is not appearing. No warning, no error it just not displaying.

Comment: Turns out the sub directory issue. It's not able to pick subdirectory.

Comment: I think subdirectory parameter is not needed if you add Lottie resources inside a group in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

You can set programmatically

```
 import Lottie
```

then add animation view in your view controller, set lottie animation in your storyboard -> animationView -> class -> AnimationView and module -> Lottie

```
 @IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!

 //Initialise a Lottie view with frame
    let customAnimationView = AnimationView(name: "Your lotti file name")
    customAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

    //Do your configurations
    customAnimationView.loopMode = .loop
    customAnimationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore

    //And play
    customAnimationView.play() 
    animationView.addSubview(customAnimationView)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the lottie document you should call

> play()

function inside viewDidAppear.

```
public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    animationView.play()
}
```

Please check the following link

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/blob/master/Example/lottie-swift/ViewController.swift

> NOTE : In some case you need to check sub directory problem

You need to add **Folder References**

Not a **Groups**

for more information on this section please check the following link.

http://www.thomashanning.com/xcode-groups-folder-references/

Comment: please check my updated answer. I hope that will solve your problem